# Query to search value in side array of object

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to apply criteria inside object of array if it matches, but I am not able to find any documentation or example where I can find that using `spring-data-cosmosdb` library. I am using `2.3.0` version of library.

Example of Json

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "address" : [
    {
     "street" : "abc" 
     ...         
    },
    {
     "street" : "efg" 
     ...
    }
  ]
}
```

I wan to search all documents in which `address` is having street name equals `"abc"`. Below is spring boot code that I am using to search in cosmosDb. But it is not returning expected results.

```
    List<Criteria> criteriaList = new ArrayList<>();
    criteriaList.add(Criteria.getInstance(CriteriaType.IN, "addresses.street", Collections.singletonList("abc")));
    List<User> users = cosmosTemplate.find(new DocumentQuery(criteriaList.get(0), CriteriaType.AND)), User.class, COLLECTION_NAME);
```

I also tried with `address[0].street`, but it is throwing exception of operation not supported.

Comment: its com.microsoft.azure.spring.data.cosmosdb.core.cosmosTemplate. which query you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Strongly recommend upgrading to [spring-data-cosmosdb v3](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-sdk-java-spring-v3) (at least version 3.22.0). The v2 connector has been legacy for some time. Using the latest connector, the below would accomplish your goal.

```
Criteria filterCriteria = Criteria.getInstance(CriteriaType.ARRAY_CONTAINS, "address",
        Collections.singletonList(new ObjectMapper().readTree("{\"street\":\"abc\"}")),
        Part.IgnoreCaseType.NEVER);
CosmosQuery cosmosQuery = new CosmosQuery(filterCriteria);
Iterable<User> results = cosmosTemplate.find(cosmosQuery, User.class, COLLECTION_NAME);
for (User user : results)
    System.out.println("doc id: " + user.getId());
```